# Conversion failed when converting date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a date stored as a `varchar(50)` `1/7/1958'`  I am looking to convert it to a date.

I have tried this;

`select convert(date,(left(date_of_birth,10))` and get the following error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

when I remove the column name and hard code the date

`select convert(date,(left('1/7/1958',10)))`  I get this `1958-01-07`  I want to convert and insert into a date field.

This is the code I am working with .

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE, (LEFT(date_of_birth, 10)))))
FROM employee_temp WHERE date_of_birth NOT IN ('0000160-1'
                                      , '0000354-1'
                                      , '0000423-1'
                                      , '0000478-1'
                                      , '0000509-1'
                                      , '0000616-1'
                                      , '0001017-1'
                                      , '0001183-1'
                                      , '0001208-1'
                                      , '0001298-1'
                                      , '0001358-1'
                                      , '0001427-1'
                                      , '0001500-1'
                                      , '0001823-1'
                                      , '0001919-1'
                                      , '0001941-1'
                                      , '0001968-1'
                                      , '0001999-1'
                                      , '0002029-1'
                                      , '07/28/0966'
                                      , ' '
                                      , '8')
```

any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Values in your `NOT IN` condition such as `0000354-1 , 0000423-1 etc...` are not dates .. that's why you get an error , you are comparing `date` and  `char/string` datatype.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` on a date don't make sense.  These are string functions, not date functions.

Second, the simply method is to use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(date_of_birth, 10), 10)
```

Third, you might need to determine if the date is in the right format in earlier versions of SQL Server.  For this, use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN date_of_birth LIKE '[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
             THEN CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(date_of_birth, 10))
        END)
```

I note you are using format "10" but for a string with 10 characters.  Format "10" is formally MM-DD-YY.  For MM-DD-YYYY use "110".  Even if "10" works, it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your database so date is stored as a date. What you're doing is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [ISDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) funtion:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, date_of_birth)
FROM employee_temp
WHERE ISDATE(date_of_birth) = 1;
```